# Non-exhaustive pattern in my function head'

Tags: haskell

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' [[]]    = []
transpose' [[], _] = []
transpose' rows    = (map head' rows) : transpose' (map tail' rows)
  where
    head' (x:_) = x
    tail' (_:xs) = xs

matMult3 :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
matMult3 a b = [ [ sum $ zipWith (*) ar bc | bc <- (transpose' b) ] | ar <- a ]
```

Anyone got any ideas as to why this could be throwing up a non-exhaustive? I feel like there is something missing but I'm too new to haskell itself to actually know, I'm self teaching it so that might be why, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What if my input is not well-formed? E.g. `transpose' ["a", ""]`.

Answer (score 2):

Both `head'` and `tail'` don't define what happens if you provide the empty list as a parameter.  You need to define the following:

```
head' [] = ....
tail' [] = ....
```

Comment: you could create a safe version of head and tail  (which exists in the safe package already), but the type would be `[a]->Maybe a` and `[a]->Maybe [a]`.  Note that `headMay [] = Nothing`, not `[]`.  Also, note that regular `head`, `tail` define the empty list case as `head [] = error "<some message>"`, `tail [] = error "<some message>"`.

Comment: depends what you did....  You should be able to use the `error` version as is, and the warning will go away.  If you want to use the `Maybe` version, you will have to restructure the program to be able to deal with that `Maybe`, it isn't a simple replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very fluent yet in Haskell, however the following version of `transpose'` works well for non-ragged matrices:

```
transpose' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose' ([x]: xs) = [x: map singleTail' xs] where
    singleTail' [x] = x
transpose' rows = (map head rows) : transpose' (map tail rows)
```

E.g.,

```
>>> transpose' [[1], [2], [3]]
[[1,2,3]]

>>> transpose' [[1,2,3]]
[[1], [2], [3]]

>>> transpose' [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

but fails for ragged matrices:

```
>>> transpose' [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
:3:5-23: Non-exhaustive patterns in function singleTail'
```

Comment: The library `transpose` is similar to yours, except that `[]` is used as a base case (we prefer that, if possible ;-)) and that lists comprehensions are used instead of `map head` so that they fail gracefully (skipping missing elements for ragged matrices). http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#transpose